# php DOMDocument class: node tree

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument

I want to convert html syntax into a node tree (`<ul>` structure). How do I do this using the DOMDocument class?

```
$html = '

   <div>
       <p>
           <a>
       </p>
  </div>

';
```

result:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       div
        <ul>
            <li>
               p
                <ul> 
                    <li>a</li>
                </ul> 
           </li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = '<div>
       <p>
           <a>#</a>
       </p>
  </div>
';

function xml2array($xml,&$result = '') {
    foreach($xml->children() as $name => $xmlchild) {
        xml2array($xmlchild,$result);
    }
    $result = "<ul><li>".$xml->getName().$result."</li></ul>";
}
$result='';
$dd = xml2array(simplexml_load_string($xml),$result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

output

```
<ul>
    <li>
        div
        <ul>
            <li>
                p
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        a
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why dont' use DOMDocument::load() ?

Comment: What is this bit of code ( &$result = '' ) in the function parameter?

Comment: adding & is for creating reference variable.